# Resizing an image before uploading to server on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize an image in a photo app and haven't been successful yet. I'm new to photo resizing on iOS, but I swear that I'm doing this right, but my logs show:

```
Error: <WUTModelImageUploadReq> 
   [photo]: <nil>
   [extension]: <nil>
</WUTModelImageUploadReq>
```

I'm trying to set 'scaleImage' as the image in the AsyncPostFeed.m

Here is my code:

UIImage+Scaling.m

```
@implementation UIImage (Scaling)

- (UIImage *)scaleImageToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);

 CGFloat originX = 0.0;
 CGFloat originY = 0.0;

 CGRect destinationRect =
 CGRectMake(originX, originY, newSize.width, newSize.height);

 [self drawInRect:destinationRect];

 UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 return newImage;
}

@end
```

WUTPostViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UIImage *selectedImage = _imageForPost;

   CGSize scaleSize = CGSizeMake(200.0f, 200.0f);

   UIImage *scaleImage =
   [selectedImage scaleImageToSize:scaleSize];

   [self.imageViewForPost setImage:scaleImage];

   ...
}
```

WUTPostViewController.h:

```
@interface WUTPostViewController : WUTCommonViewController     <UITextViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblUserName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewForPost;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *tvDesription;

@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *imageForPost;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *scaleImage;

- (void)wsPostLikeSuccessCallbackForPostId;
- (void)wsPostLikeFailCallbackWithMessage:(NSString *)errorMessage;


@end
```

AsyncPostFeed.m:

```
- (void)uploadPhoto {

   WUTModelImageUploadReq *imageUploadReq = [[WUTModelImageUploadReq alloc]init];
   // I'm trying to set scaleImage here
   imageUploadReq.photo = [self encodeToBase64String:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.viewControllerPost.scaleImage, 0.07f)]];

   imageUploadReq.extension = @"jpg";

   NSLog(@"Error: %@", imageUploadReq);


   void (^wsSuccessHandler)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary* responseObject) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    NSLog(@"Pull Feed responseObject %@",responseObject);

    NSError *error;
    WUTModelPostImageResponse *wsResponse = [[WUTModelPostImageResponse alloc]initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)responseObject error:&error];

    if (error) {
        errorMessage = @"Failure to upload image.";
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [self postExecuteFail];
    }else{
        if (wsResponse.success) {
            WUTModelImage *imageTemp = [wsResponse.data firstObject];
            [postItem setObject:imageTemp.photo forKey:@"photo"];
            [self uploadPostFeed];

        }else{
            errorMessage = @"Failure to upload image.";
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self postExecuteFail];
        }
     }
  };
```

Comment: Post `scaleImageToSize:` code.

Comment: Ok, I added that category

Comment: May be your resizing code isn't yielding an image. Have you debug that?

Comment: if scaling isn't working then use this code http://pastebin.com/RRztgbXb

Comment: @AbidHussain Yes, the code isn't yielding and image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
Looks like you forgot to set local variable `scaleImage` to `scaleImage` property of `WUTPostViewController` class.
Try this code (last line should make the trick):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UIImage *selectedImage = _imageForPost;

   CGSize scaleSize = CGSizeMake(200.0f, 200.0f);

   UIImage *scaleImage =
   [selectedImage scaleImageToSize:scaleSize];

   [self.imageViewForPost setImage:scaleImage];
   self.scaleImage = scaleImage;

   ...
}
```

**Original Answer**
Your resizing algorithm is correct. I use the same in my project and it perfectly works.
Looks like you send `scaleImageToSize:` message to `nil` object. That's why the result of this message is `nil`.
You can verify this assumption by updating code in this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UIImage *selectedImage = _imageForPost;
   NSAssert(selectedImage != nil, @"Selected image is nil");

   CGSize scaleSize = CGSizeMake(200.0f, 200.0f);

   UIImage *scaleImage =
   [selectedImage scaleImageToSize:scaleSize];

   [self.imageViewForPost setImage:scaleImage];

   ...
}
```

As you see I added `NSAssert` call, so your application will crash with provided message if selected image is nil.
If `NSAssert` is triggered, then you need look for root cause of the problem. Basically you need verify that `_imageForPost` variable is initialized before `viewDidLoad` method is called.

Comment: The app didn't crash on the addition of `NSAssert(selectedImage != nil, @"Selected image is nil");`

Comment: @Paul, hmm, okay. Another assumption that image size is wrong. Can you add such code `NSLog(@"%@", _imageForPost)`, and take a look what image size is printed in console?

Comment: @Paul, one more thing about this code: `[self encodeToBase64String:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.viewControllerPost.scaleImage, 0.07f)]];` Did you set local variable `scaleImage` to `viewControllerPost` property `scaleImage`? Because what I see is: in `viewDidLoad` you used local variable `scaleImage` but in `AsyncPostFeed.m` you used view controller property `scaleImage`.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", _imageForPost)` didn't render anything in the console.

Comment: It is here where I think I'm setting `imageForPost` to `scaleImage`. Then I'm passing it to `[self encodeToBase64String:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.viewControllerPost.scaleImage, 0.07f)]];`

Comment: The code works if I do `[self encodeToBase64String:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.viewControllerPost.imageForPost, 0.07f)]];` but the image doesn't resize.

Comment: That did it! Man, I was really scratching my head on that one. Seems so obvious now.

Comment: @Paul, I understand you, sometimes it happens:)

Answer (score 0):

Please check first image are not null

```
 CGSize size1=CGSizeMake(300,300);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size1);
 [selectgalleryimage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,size1.width, size1.height)];
 UIImage *SELECTED_IMG1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. How do I integrate this example into my code?